# How to add columns into SQL database from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "names" which looks like
|name |
|-----|
|name1|
|name2|
|name3|
|.....|
From this table, I want to use the names as column names for another table "form"
|id|name1|name2|name3|...

The items under "names" are not fixed. I don't know exactly how many items are there.
How do I create this table "form" like this by using php and SQL?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question what you need is to have a reference of a table in another one. You can achieve this using foreign keys. They allow you to reference entries of table in another.
For example if I have a table "students" and another one "parents" and I want to know who are the parents of one student I can have in my table "students" a field "ID" that will identify my students uniquely (primary key) and then I will use this identifier in my table "parents" (as a foreign key).
Hence, I will not be able to add a parent with and invalid student ID (that will mean, the unknown student has 'parent_name' as parent which would make no sense).

Primary, and Foreign are SQL topics